# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jconfirm

Good day, I'm using
[jconfirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/)
 to my website project but I'm facing a weird problem that I can't solve by my own, please see my code below.

```
$.confirm({
    title: 'Add Patient',
   theme: 'material',
    backgroundDismissAnimation: 'glow',
    type:'blue',
    typeAnimated: true,
    content: '' +
    '<form action="" class="formName" style ="margin: 10px;">' +
    '<div class="form-group">' +
    '<label>ID NUMBER</label>' +
    '<input type="text" class="id_number form-control" value="my id" required />' +
    '</div>' +
    '</form>',
    buttons: {
        formSubmit: {
            text: 'Submit',
            btnClass: 'btn-blue',
            action: function () {
            }
        },
        cancel: function () {
            //close
        },
    },
    onContentReady: function () {
        this.$content.find('.id_number').change(function(){
            var a = this.$content.find('.id_number').val();
             alert(a);
        });
    }
});
```

If you try to run that code it will return an error says.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

But the weird thing is if I change the code like this.

```
onContentReady: function () {
                var a = this.$content.find('.id_number').val();
                 alert(a);
        }
```

The error is gone  and the alert pop-up.

My problem is how can I get the value of input inside the change() method? please help or what is the correct way to make this code works?

```
onContentReady: function () {
            this.$content.find('.id_number').change(function(){
                var a = this.$content.find('.id_number').val();
                 alert(a);
            });
```

Comment: try doing `console.log(this)` just above `var a = ...`. Value of `this` is probably not what you are expecting.

Comment: the console.log return `<input type="text" class="id_number form-control" required="">`

Comment: So that means `this` inside `change()` handler gives the `HTMLElement` and not the `jconfirm` object as you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `this` is different inside the `change()` function, to check that you can log the value.

As a workaround, you can keep a reference to it and use the reference.

You can also use `bind()` to bind the value of `this` to the event handler. Or check different other ways using `call()` or `apply`.

```
onContentReady: function() {
    var myReferenceToThis = this;
    this.$content.find('.id_number').change(function() {
      var a = myReferenceToThis.$content.find('.id_number').val();
      alert(a);
});
```

Or in your case, as @Phil suggested, simply do...

```
onContentReady: function() {
    var myReferenceToThis = this;
    this.$content.find('.id_number').change(function() {
      var a = $(this).val();
      alert(a);
 });
```

Comment: Or even just `this.value` as the `change` event handler will bind the element to the callback

Comment: @Phil That would be perfect for this case, I didnt actually check the code inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement the other response, which should be marked as correct, there are three ways to define `this`.

1. Function call (e.g., f()) - this refers to the global object.
2. Method call (e.g., a.f()) - this refers to the object to the left of the dot (sometimes called the receiving object).
3. New (constructor) call - this refers to a newly allocated object.

Your `.change(...)` call is an example of the second in the list above. @sabithpocker's solution saves the reference to `this` before the value of `this` is changed.

Comment: great explanation

Comment: Just for brevity, we have Default Binding, Implicit Binding, Explicit Binding, Hard Binding and new Binding as explained in detail [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)